# How to use mapstruct to automatically map Entity and Entity objects inside Entity to fields in Dto?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, mapstruct

```
public class boardEntity {

     @Id
     private UUID boardId;
     private String content;
     private UserInfoEntity user;
}
```

and

```
public class UserInfoEntity {
    
     @Id
     private UUID userId;
     private String userName;
     private String userEmail;
     private String userPhone;
}
```

I want Result

```
public class ResponseDto {
     private UUID boardId;  // << BoardEntity Field
     private String content; // << BoardEntity Field
     private UUID userId;  // << BoardEntity in UserInfoEntity Field
     private String userName;  // << BoardEntity in UserInfoEntity Field
     ...
}
```

I am using mapstruct.

I have a UserEntity inside a BoardEntity. (join)

The DTO I want is to take out all the fields in each entity and create them.

Take out boardId and content from BoardEntity,

Get userId and userName from UserEntity in BoardEntity.

Create a DTO with these 4 fields, this is what I want.

It's not that I don't know how.

```
@Mapping(target = "userId", source = "user.userId")
@Mapping(target = "userName", source = "user.userName")
ResponseDto toDto (BoardEntity board);
```

I've currently implemented it this way and it works without problems.
(Reproduced from memory, so it may be slightly different, but the method is the same.)

The problem is that I only wrote 2 @Mapping right now, but there are actually more fields to fill out.

And they're all doing manual mapping, so I think something's wrong.

Is there another way to get all objects inside Entity and map them to fields in Dto?
(The field names are the same.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapStruct offers a way to define mapping of unmapped target properties from a certain source.

e.g. in your example you would like to map the unmapped target properties `userId` and `userName` from the `UserInfoEntity` into the `ResponseDto` you can do that with a single `@Mapping`

```java
@Mapping(target = ".", source ="user")
ResponseDto toDto(BoardEntity board);
```